# Not able to understand why function returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function to remove the underscore if it is the first character of the string.

The function converts the input to uppercase and get the first character and after a validation if requires it removes the first character. Then again calling the same function with modified input to re validate. If it pass the condition I am returning the modified word from the `else`.But somehow it is returning `undefined`

```js
let word = '__Hello_World';

function removeFirstUnderscore(ipWord) {
  // converting to uppercase and getting first character;
  let getFirstCharacter = ipWord.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0); // 95
  // now checking if first character is in this range between 65 & 95
  if (getFirstCharacter <= 65 || getFirstCharacter >= 94) {
    // remove the first character & again call the recursive function to revalidate
    let removedFirstCharWord = ipWord.split('').splice(1).join('');
    console.log('**** ', removedFirstCharWord);
    removeFirstUnderscore(removedFirstCharWord)
  } else {
    // if first character is within range then return it
    return ipWord;
  }
}
console.log(removeFirstUnderscore(word))
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an `if` statement.

If the condition is **not** met, you `return ipWord`.

If the condition **is** met, you **call** `removeFirstUnderscore(removedFirstCharWord)` but **return** nothing.

If you want to return the result of a recursive call, then you need to `return` it.

```
return removeFirstUnderscore(removedFirstCharWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `return` statement in your `if` block.